# PHP regex to find CR 3492161 or cr 3492161

Tags: php, regex, cakephp, yii, reference

I am trying a PHP regex to find CR 3492161 or cr 3492161. I have tried using the following regex however it is not working. Requesting your help. :-)

```
'CR\s/^\d{7}$/'
'CR\h/^\d{7}$/'
'CR /^\d{7}$/'
```

**Note :** CR is not a Carriage return, perhaps it is just a Pattern CR.

**Code :**

```
<?php
namespace Shedanigans;
use Application\Filter\Linkify;
class Module
{
  public function onBootstrap()
  {
    Linkify::addCallback(
      function ($value, $escaper) {
        if (strcasecmp($value, 'CR\s/^\d{7}$/')) {
          // not a hit; tell caller we did not handle this one
          return false;
        }
        return '<a target="_new" href="https://xtz.abc.com/">'
               . $escaper->escapeHtml($value) . "</a>";
       },
      'CR\s/^\d{7}$/',
      strlen('CR\s/^\d{7}$/')
    );
  }
    public function getConfig()
    {
    return array();
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could try this:

```
(?:CR|cr)\s[0-9]{7}
```

[image: Regular expression visualization]

[Debuggex Demo](https://www.debuggex.com/r/-qoujMeFi6_EK9aM)

Answer (score 1):

The `strcasecmp` function is binary safe case-insensitive string comparison, no relations to regex. The function to perform a regex checking is `preg_match`, [PHP Docs](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-match.php).

You should try: `preg_match('/^CR\s\d{7}$/i', $value)`

This Regex will accept CR string (case-insensitive), a space and 7 numbers!

Answer (score 1):

Try this expression

```
preg_match('/^[Cc][Rr]\s[0-9]{7}$/', $value);
```

**EDIT:** 
limited just for CR and cr not Cr and not cR

```
preg_match('/^(CR|cr)\s[0-9]{7}$/', $value);
```

you can test your RegExr here:
http://regexr.com/3dum5

Comment: This would also validate `Cr 3492161` and `cR 3492161`

Comment: yes of course if you can limit change to ^(CR|cr)\s[0-9]{7}$